# Labjack Humidity Probe Example

Tags: c, temperature, probe

I realize this might be a long shot, but does anyone have an example of using the EI-1050 probe with a Labjack controller in something C-related? I'm currently using a Labjack U12 if it matters.

It installed 2 examples, ljsht and ljsht-multi, that seem to be doing something related to it, but I can't find the source code.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You might have better luck at chiphacker.com if this question starts growing mold. Its a stack exchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The applications you mentioned are written in LabVIEW, and the source code is available.  Use LJSHT.exe to make sure your EI-1050 is connected right and giving good readings.

Refer to the EI-1050 datasheet for information about interfacing with the U12.

Then start with a basic C example like "VC6 Simple Example" or "U12 Dev-C++ Example":

http://labjack.com/support/u12/examples

... and add a call to the function SHT1X() described in Section 4.31 of the U12 User's Guide.

Comment: I figured it out, you're right, it was the `SHT1X` function. Weird name for it, but it worked!